# vanilla js vs jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to do an ajax call with vanilla js.

In **jQuery**, I have this working ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/faq/ajax",
    datatype: 'json',
    type:"POST",
    data: {search:'banana'},
    success:function(r) {
    console.log(r['name'])
    }
});
```

**Vanilla JS:**

```
var search = document.getElementById('searchbarfaq').value;
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", "/faq/ajax", true);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
  console.log("Success: " + JSON.parse(r.responseText));
  var a = JSON.parse(r.responseText);
  console.log(a.name); //also tried a['name']...
};
r.send("search=banana");
```

The vanilla js call just logs this to the console:

```
"Success: [object Object]" 
Array [  ]
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're ajax call looks fine. Whatever your controller on the other end is sending back must be wrong somehow. You should print out the responseText so you can see what the JSON.parse is actually trying to parse

Comment: What is the value of r.responseText? what are you expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told the server how you are encoding the data in the request.

```
r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Presumably whatever server side handler you are using to process the data isn't parsing it correctly, so isn't finding the data it needs, and then returns a blank array as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond printing out `r.responseText` to the console, you can also inspect the HTTP response from dev tools built into the browser itself.

On Firefox, for instance:

1. Tools -> Web Developer -> Network
   (this should open a panel listing all the HTTP requests and responses)
2. Go through the process you use to execute your AJAX call
3. Look at the corresponding HTTP request by clicking on the item in the list in the panel shown in step 1 (a panel on the right should appear with more details about the request and subsequent response)

Digging around in these tools can give you a lot of insight into the the HTTP request your code is making and the values it's getting back in the response.

A similar process can be performed for all the major browsers out there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [simple and lightweight Ajax module](https://lucidar.me/en/javascript-modules/ajax/) with the following syntax:

```
import {ajax} from '/path/to/ajax.min.js';

ajax('https://api_url.com')
.data('key-1','Value-1')
.data('key-2','Value-2')
.send()
.then((data) => { console.log ('success', data) })
.catch((status) => { console.log ('failed', status)} );
```